# Can't connect to multiplayer in ACB on XBox-360

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I only ever made it to level 19 in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood and wanted to go back to level up. It would be nice to get the few remaining achievements. However, I can't seem to connect to any servers. It will say it's waiting for other people, and that 1/6 has connected, for 10-15 minutes usually before I give up. Even if I start my own game nobody connects.

I realize it's an old game, but is there really nobody playing? Is my connection too slow?

Comment: ACB multiplayer is mostly dead nowadays, especially during the week (at least on PC). Your best hope at finding games is to play on the weekend, you might find a handful of players to play with and you'll most likely be playing a Wanted game.